# cordova unzip files from www folder

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to unzip files from `www` folder to external location using [zip plugin](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip).

I assign external data directory to a variable `folder` when application start.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function (folder) {
                $filex.folder= folder;
});
```

then i call dataUnzip.

```
dataUnzip:function(){
        var wwwPath = window.location.pathname;
        var basePath = 'file://'+ wwwPath.substring(0,wwwPath.length-10);
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(basePath+'ex.zip',
        function(fileDB){
            alert('success! database was found')
                unzipFiles(fileDB);

        },
        function(){
            alert('failure! database was not found')
        });

        function unzipFiles(fileDB){
            zip.unzip(fileDB,$filex.folder.nativeURL + "",
                function (a) {
                    alert('Zip decompressed successfully' + a);
                }
           );
       }
}
```

but i always get output as `Zip decompressed successfully -1`.`-1` means unzip has failed.it works if i unzip .zip from external location like `externalDataDirectory` .but i want to unzip a file exist in www directory.
is there any way to get descriptive error ?instead of -1.and what could be the reason for unzip failure ?

here is a screenshot of www folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Read here for documentation about file permissions etc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)

External Data Directory is not available on all platforms, what platform are you testing on?

Can you not just store the files unzipped in your application directory?

Otherwise, you may need to use different locations for each platform and use the merges folder.

Comment: well i'm focusing on android.the problem is not with External Data Directory.i can unzip anything in external directories.the problem it doesn't work when i'm trying to unzip from www folder to external.basically problem is with www folder

Comment: I guess you will need to copy the zip from the www folder to the external data directory and unzip it from there. I guess it's trying to write something to the www folder and can't as it doesn't have permissions to write in the www folder.